# Image not displayed in firefox in html img tag

Tags: html, image

I have an img tag in a html page. My img source is a file on a remote server. When i try to render the img in firefox as

```
file://///server/folder1/folder2/name.jpg
```

it renders correctly. But when i try to put the same url in img tag as:

```
<img alt="" src="file://///server/folder1/folder2/name.jpg" />
```

it does not renders in firefox. IE renders it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the default behavior of Firefox for security reasons.

Here is a way you can change this default behavior :

> This could be turned off in firefox:
>
> - type "about:config" in the address bar and accept "i'll be careful"
> - ```
>      find "security.checkloaduri" in older versions or
>   ```
>
> "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy"
> in newer versions of firefox and
> change the value to "false"
>
> - restart firefox
>
> That should do it for you. You have
> more information here:
>
> ```
> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy
> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.origin_policy
> ```

Regards,

Max

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However as my img tag is on my website, I cannot ask my users to do this change in Firefox behavior. Is there a way I can modify my img src to display it correctly?
UPDATE
Even after making the change, I am not able to display the img correctly.

Comment: Did you try the solutions provided in the link ? Did you restart firefox ? Besides, couldn't you store the file locally ? It would be more "standard" and closer to classic HTML.

Comment: Yes, I did follow the steps in link and restarted Firefox too. My application displays uploaded images by users. So have to get the image from file share.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like you have no solution for the other users (for the same security reasons) : http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work. For your test case, check if you really used slash / instead of backslash \